# MAC OSX Heimdall Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!

Tags: rooting, root-access, clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-note-2, heimdall

I am getting the error: **Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!”** when using *Heimdall* on Mac OSx.

**The error in terminal:**

```
Kathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY ./recovery.img --no-reboot
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Uploading RECOVERY
100%
ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!
ERROR: RECOVERY upload failed!

Ending session...

heimdall prERROR: Failed to send end session packet!
Releasing device interface...
```

**My PIT information in terminal:**

```
Kathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ heimdall print-pit --verbose
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
ERROR: Failed to detect compatible download-mode device.
Kathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ heimdall print-pit --verbose
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
      Manufacturer: "SAMSUNG"
           Product: "Gadget Serial"

            length: 18
      device class: 2
               S/N: 0
           VID:PID: 0xxx:xxxD
         bcdDevice: 0xxx
   iMan:iProd:iSer: 1:2:0
          nb confs: 1

interface[0].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 1
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 02.02.01
       endpoint[0].address: 83
           max packet size: 0010
          polling interval: 09

interface[1].altsetting[0]: num endpoints = 2
   Class.SubClass.Protocol: 0A.00.00
       endpoint[0].address: 81
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
       endpoint[1].address: 02
           max packet size: 0200
          polling interval: 00
Claiming interface...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

Entry Count: 20
Unknown 1: 1598902083
Unknown 2: 844251476
Unknown 3: 30797
Unknown 4: 19757
Unknown 5: 19780
Unknown 6: 0
Unknown 7: 0
Unknown 8: 0


--- Entry #0 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 80
Attributes: 2 (STL Read-Only)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 0
Partition Block Count: 1734
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOOTLOADER
Flash Filename: sboot.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #1 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 81
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 1734
Partition Block Count: 312
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: TZSW
Flash Filename: tz.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #2 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 70
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 34
Partition Block Count: 16
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PIT
Flash Filename: t0.pit
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #3 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 71
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 50
Partition Block Count: 2048
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: MD5HDR
Flash Filename: md5.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #4 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 1
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8192
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOTA0
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #5 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 2
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 16384
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOTA1
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #6 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 3
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 24576
Partition Block Count: 40960
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: EFS
Flash Filename: efs.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #7 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 4
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 65536
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: m9kefs1
Flash Filename: m9kefs1.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #8 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 5
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 73728
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: m9kefs2
Flash Filename: m9kefs2.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #9 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 6
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 81920
Partition Block Count: 8192
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: m9kefs3
Flash Filename: m9kefs3.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #10 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 7
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 90112
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: PARAM
Flash Filename: param.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #11 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 8
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 106496
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: BOOT
Flash Filename: boot.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #12 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 9
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 122880
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: RECOVERY
Flash Filename: recovery.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #13 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 10
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 139264
Partition Block Count: 180224
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: RADIO
Flash Filename: modem.bin
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #14 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 11
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 319488
Partition Block Count: 524288
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: TOMBSTONES
Flash Filename: tombstones.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #15 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 12
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 843776
Partition Block Count: 3145728
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: CACHE
Flash Filename: cache.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #16 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 13
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 3989504
Partition Block Count: 4718592
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: SYSTEM
Flash Filename: system.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #17 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 14
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8708096
Partition Block Count: 40960
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: HIDDEN
Flash Filename: hidden.img
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #18 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 15
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 1 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8749056
Partition Block Count: 16384
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: OTA
Flash Filename: -
FOTA Filename: 


--- Entry #19 ---
Binary Type: 0 (AP)
Device Type: 2 (MMC)
Identifier: 16
Attributes: 5 (Read/Write)
Update Attributes: 5 (FOTA)
Partition Block Size/Offset: 8765440
Partition Block Count: 0
File Offset (Obsolete): 0
File Size (Obsolete): 0
Partition Name: USERDATA
Flash Filename: userdata.img
FOTA Filename: remained

Ending session...
Rebooting device...
Releasing device interface...
```

**The Heimdall version in terminal**

```
Kathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ david$ heimdall info
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Heimdall utilises libusbx for all USB communication:
    http://www.libusb.org/

libusbx is licensed under the LGPL-2.1:
    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/licenses.html#LGPL

Kathryns-MacBook-Pro:~ david$
```

Not sure what all I am doing incorrectly but any help would be great to solve this issue so that I can upload my own ROM using modded recovery for my Verizon Galaxy Note 2.